# HTML: Form POST select return option text

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have next HTML:

```html
<select name="fb_query[1][type]">
<option val="1">Page posts</option>
<option val="2">Page feeds</option>
<option val="3">Page fotos</option>
<option val="4">User posts</option>
<option val="5">User fotos</option>
</select>
```

Select generated by javascript but maybe its not a problem.

When I submit form, in the post metadata $_POST['fb_query'][1]['type'] I get "Page fotos" not "3" ..
Maybe someone know where is problem ?

Comment: "val" is not a valid attribute for the option tag. You should use "value". https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct html attribute is value not val:

```
<select name="fb_query[1][type]">
    <option value="1">Page posts</option>
    <option value="2">Page feeds</option>
    <option value="3">Page fotos</option>
    <option value="4">User posts</option>
    <option value="5">User fotos</option>
</select>
```